# how to pop up alarm even when the application is closed

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm developing a location based alarm which is an Android application.

All the coding part has been done.

But the alarm alert dialog is not displaying when the application is closed.

Please help me, I'm trying to pop up the alarm even when user is using another application or is in the home screen.

The code of my alarm at the moment is shown below:

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(LocAlarmProject.this, R.raw.airtel); 

mp.start();         

// LocAlarmProject.this below is what's causing the problem:
final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(LocAlarmProject.this);

builder.setTitle(disp_title);

builder.setMessage(disp_desc);

builder.setIcon(R.drawable.alarm);

builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                        

     mp.stop();

}

 });

 builder.show();
```

Comment: You would have to create an activity and style it like a dialog. You cannot open a dialog created by a closed activty.

Comment: I'm new to android. not having much idea about this. Can you please let me know about this or give any link,so that i can code it. I'm trying this from 2 days. please help.

Comment: are you suggesting about, android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you are looking for [Service.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Copied and Paste:

> A Service is an application component representing either an
>   application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not
>   interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other
>   applications to use. Each service class must have a corresponding
>    declaration in its package's AndroidManifest.xml. Services
>   can be started with Context.startService() and Context.bindService().

Answer (score 1):

Use Notification service to keep track of the status.....visit......http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this requires a few steps. Sorry, it's not trivial if you haven't done it before:

First, you're going to use Android's built-in `AlarmManager` to schedule the time you want your app to be activated. You schedule a new alarm with the time to wake up and a `PendingIntent`.

Second, create your `PendingIntent` that's used to activate your app for the time to show the alarm.

Third, you can handle this Intent several ways, the most common is to create a class that extends `BroadcastReceiver` to receive the Intent. This class is notified when it's time to show the alarm. The Intent that you created and put inside your PendingIntent is passed to its `onReceive()` method. You pass this information to your app to display the alert dialog. --- You can alternatively just register your main app to receive the Intent instead, then override the `onNewIntent(Intent)` method in your Activity.

Four, register your `BroadcastReceiver` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. This is also the place to register this receiver to listen for the Intent you created. You do this using the `<intent-filter>` tag.

Five, (optional) if you want your alarm to display even if the phone is asleep, and you want to make sure it doesn't go back to sleep before the user acknowledges the alarm, you'll need to obtain a WAKE_LOCK to do so.

The reason this is preferable to using a Service is it doesn't consume resources just to wait for the alarm, and also it still works if Android decides to kill your app free up memory. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: But my application is not a time based alarm. It is a location based one. On change in location i want to pop up the alarm.